# Carousel Loop Issue (Items disappear after one loop)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I used a tutorial from codrops to create a carousel. I am not super savvy with JS or using anything JS related without reference code, so I merely adopted and modified the existing code from the tutorial. The issue that I am having is relating to the loopback. While using the carousel cycling through, the content works fine, but when you open one of the items and cycle through, it causes the carousel to get out of order.

Huge problem because items start disappearing when you press left-right. Anyone able to help on this one?

Below is the code I'm using on the site page.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.carouFredSel-packed.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#leaderthumbs').carouFredSel({
        synchronise: ['#leaderdetails', false, true],
        auto: false,
        width: '100%',
        items: {
            visible: 3,
            start: 0
        },
        scroll: {
            onBefore: function (data) {
                data.items.old.eq(1).removeClass('selected');
                data.items.visible.eq(1).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next'
    });

    jQuery('#leaderdetails').carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        scroll: {
            fx: 'fade'
        }
    });

    jQuery('#leaderthumbs div').click(function () {
        $('#leaderthumbs').trigger('slideTo', [this, -1]);
    });
    jQuery('#leaderthumbs div:eq(1)').addClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem may be in carouFredSel-packed.js

Comment: You have only 1 item? Can you put in your HTML?

Comment: @JAL I have JS files, wrote with some PHP to use handlers for backend editing in Wordpress. I can send you the site, but rather not post it here publicly.

Comment: @JAL I spoke too soon, but the URL for the site is located at http://bit.ly/155431r ; Could you please help me out with this issue? It's been stumping me forever. I don't know where to even start. I used bit.ly to mask the URL for the client. Thanks.